# my MSXML2 code not working after 24. loop

Tags: vba, msxml2

the code below doesn't save the data, usually after 24 loops. why might that be? thank you.

```
Public Sub XmlHttpTutorial()
For x = 1 To 50
Dim xmlhttp As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60, myurl As String
myurl = "https://www.etsy.com/shop/SilverHandwriting/reviews?page=" & x
xmlhttp.Open "GET", myurl, False
xmlhttp.send
Sheets("sayfa1").Cells(x, "a") = xmlhttp.responseText
 Next x
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you try printing the xmlhttp.status in the loop?

Comment: I didn't try. rather, I don't know how to print it.

Comment: Start with `Sheets("sayfa1").Cells(x, "a") = xmlhttp.status` and see whether you are getting all 200s or something else. [status codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status)

Comment: status=200 until the 10th query. then status=429(429 Too Many Requests). but I don't know how to solve this problem.

Comment: It may be that you need to leave a pause between requests/batches of n requests; use a back-off retry mechanism; rotate proxies...... check what fair usage is under T&C.....Too many requests in a short period might be interpreted as a DoS attack or some such.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick replies. I will try to do what you said. Yours truly